# how to encrypt word document using publickey in php

Tags: php, encryption, phpseclib

I have a problem, I want to encrypt word docs(which have only 10 Kb) using public key, and it must decrypt with private key.
I already created key pair using phpseclib library.
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html
and I can encrypt and decrypt string using that library. but I don't know how to encrypt file using key pair.
is there any method for this.(or using file_get_contents)
thanks for all

```
<?php

//create word docx using phpdocx
require("phpDocx.php"); 
    $phpdocx = new phpdocx("word_temp\loan_app_temp.docx");
                                //assign
                                $upfno='999';
                                $loanid_db='1234';
                                $phpdocx->assign("#upfno#","$upfno"); 
                                $phpdocx->assign("#loanid#","$loanid_db"); 
                                $phpdocx->assign("#fullname#","$name"); 
                                $phpdocx->assign("#initials#","$initials"); 

                                $phpdocx->save("word_gen\loan_docs\la_".$upfno."_".$loanid_db.".docx"); // sucessfully created.

// create key pair using phpseclib
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//$rsa->setPassword('layanthi@123');
extract($rsa->createKey());
//echo "$privatekey<br />$publickey";
echo $privatekeydata=$privatekey;
echo '<br />';
echo $pubkey=$publickey;  //key pair genarated - ok

//encryption using pubkey - commented snippet from phpseclib
$file="word_gen\loan_docs\la_".$upfno."_".$loanid_db.".docx";
$message=file_get_contents($file);
 function rsa_encrypt($key, $message) {
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); 
    $rsa->loadKey($key); 
    $encrypted = base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($message)); 
    return $encrypted;
}
echo $encrypt_file=rsa_encrypt($pubkey, $message);
//from here i want to save encryptted file to encrypt folder like
//$savepath="encrypt\la_".$upfno."_".$loanid_db.".docx";  but i dont know how to do that

//Deryption using phpseclib function is here - but how to use it for above  encryption
 function rsa_decrypt($key, $package) {
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); 
    $rsa->loadKey($key); 
    $decrypted = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($package)); 
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Yes. file_get_contents(), encrypt($contents), file_put contents().  Ideally you would test out your theories, and provide code and errors here if something goes wrong.

Comment: i will upload my code as soon as posible

Comment: here is my code, please help to my question, thanks

Comment: You'd really be better off generating, at encrypt time, a random string, using phpseclib's `crypt_random_string(32)` or something and then encrypting that random string with RSA and using that random string's first 16 bytes as the key for AES and second 16 bytes as the IV for AES. That'd be a ton faster. phpseclib's Crypt_RSA will split a file that's larger than the key into multiple chunks that are the appropriate length but you really shouldn't encrypt anything longer than the key anyway if only for the speed issue.

Comment: @neubet thanks for your help. but unfortunatly i can not develop that, because i didnt much about crypto

Comment: You can see an example of how to do it at http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/interop.html . Click on PHP Bindings / seal() / open() and then click phpseclib for both "sealing" and "opening" (you'll see what I mean when you go there). That example uses RC4 and you could use that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $encrypt_file=rsa_encrypt($pubkey, $message);
$savepath="word_gen\encrypt\la_".$upfno."_".$loanid_db.".docx";

file_put_contents($savepath, $encrypt_file);

//Deryption using phpseclib function is here - but how to use it for above  encryption

 function rsa_decrypt($key, $package) {
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); 
    $rsa->loadKey($key); 
    $decrypted = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($package)); 
    return $decrypted;
}

//get encrypt file
$encfile="word_gen\encrypt\la_".$upfno."_".$loanid_db.".docx";
$epackage=file_get_contents($encfile);

echo $decryptfile= rsa_decrypt($privatekeydata, $epackage);
$savepath_de="word_gen\decrypt\la_".$upfno."_".$loanid_db.".docx";

file_put_contents($savepath_de, $encrypt_file);

?>
```